# How can I tell vscode to use correct headers and compiler for embedded cross-compilation on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gcc, embedded

I'm doing cross compilation for ARM Cortex M microcontrollers, on Linux, using gcc, and having trouble getting vscode to recognize the config.

When I compile my code from the command line, it uses the correct header files:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -H main.c /usr/local/include/cmsis/cmsis_f4/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32f446xx.s -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wundef -Wshadow -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat-truncation -Wconversion -DSTM32F446RE -DSTM32F446XX -g3 -O0 -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -I. -I/usr/local/include/cmsis/cmsis_core/CMSIS/Core/Include -I/usr/local/include/cmsis/cmsis_f4/Include -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16  -Tlink.ld - -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--print-gc-sections -Wl,-Map=firmware.map -o firmware.elf
. /usr/include/newlib/inttypes.h
...
```

However, Visual Studio Code thinks I'm using the Clang header files.  When I click on the `#include <inttypes.h>`, I see the LLVM file:

```
/*===---- inttypes.h - Standard header for integer printf macros ----------===*\
 *
 * Part of the LLVM Project, under the Apache License v2.0 with LLVM Exceptions.
...
```

I therefore get false positive red squiggles.

I deleted the entire Clang reference from `c_cpp_properties.json`, which now is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ARM",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include/cmsis/cmsis_core/CMSIS/Core/Include",
                "/usr/local/include/cmsis/cmsis_f4/Include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "STM32F446RE",
                "STM32F446XX"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu23",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

but somehow vscode still is trying to use clang (or at least the header files it provides).

How can I tell vscode intellisense and error squiggles to use the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler and the system include files (which that compiler uses)?

(The project has a Makefile, which vscode is able to find and parse.)

Comment: it is intellisense not the "real" compilation.

Comment: @0___________ Yes - I would like intellisense to work.  I can compile via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a cache issue.  Coming back a few hours later, the intellisense seems to be updated.  Most likely: The default compiler was set to clang, intellisense populated from that, and switching it to gcc isn't automatic, but repopulates slowly in the background.